# Printing multiple PDFs with the filename in the header or footer

Tags: powershell, ms-word, automation

I need to print a large folder of PDFs with the filename in the header or footer.  My company locks down my PC pretty well, so my options are limited (cannot install anything).  We have Adobe Reader only.

I know Powershell and was thinking it may be possible to create a document using Word, insert the PDF, add the header and then print.

It probably could be done with just Word too with scripting.

But I am open to other ideas.

Comment: Whether you can use Word for this depends on which version you're working with. Only 2013 and later can open a PDF file - but note they do OPEN it and convert to a Word document...

Comment: It is Word 2010 so that won't work I guess.